# Estimate a complex modulus

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I have to estimate the following quantity
$$\vert e^{iz\vert x\vert}-e^{i\lambda\vert x\vert}\vert^2$$
where $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$, $\Im z>0$ and $\lambda>0$.
So I write
$$\vert e^{i\Re z\vert x\vert}e^{-\Im z\vert x\vert}-\cos(\lambda\vert x\vert)-i\sin(\lambda\vert x\vert)\vert^2$$
Putting $A=\Re z$ and $B=\Im z$ I have
$$\vert (e^{-B\vert x\vert}\cos(A\vert x\vert)-\cos(\lambda\vert x\vert))+i(e^{-B\vert x\vert}\sin(A\vert x\vert)-\sin(\lambda\vert x\vert))\vert^2=$$
$$=(e^{-B\vert x\vert}\cos(A\vert x\vert)-\cos(\lambda\vert x\vert))^2+(e^{-B\vert x\vert}\sin(A\vert x\vert)-\sin(\lambda\vert x\vert))^2$$
Making calculations I obtain
$$\vert e^{iz\vert x\vert}-e^{i\lambda\vert x\vert}\vert^2\leq 4$$
Is something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's denote $z=a+ib$. Then

$$\left | e^{iz\vert x\vert}-e^{i\lambda\vert x\vert}\right |^2 =
\left | e^{ia\vert x\vert}e^{-b|x|}-e^{i\lambda\vert x\vert}\right |^2$$

Using $|u+v|^2 = |u|^2 + 2Re\{uv^*\} + |v|^2$ we get

$$\left | e^{ia\vert x\vert}e^{-b|x|}-e^{i\lambda\vert x\vert}\right |^2 =
e^{-2b|x|} + 2Re\left\{ e^{ia\vert x\vert}e^{-b|x|}e^{-i\lambda\vert x\vert}\right\} + 1 =\\
e^{-2b|x|} + 2e^{-b|x|}\cos\left[(a-\lambda)|x|\right] + 1 \le \left( e^{-b|x|} + 1\right)^2 \le 4$$
The one but last inequality is true because $-1\le\cos(\alpha)\le 1$ for any real-valued $\alpha$.
If we know nothing about $b$ then your upper bound is the same as mine. If there is more information about $b$ then we can make the upper bound tighter.

Answer (score 0):

For $\;\;z=a+ib\;,\;\;x\in\mathbb{R}^3\;,\;\;b:=\operatorname{Im} z>0\;,\;\;\lambda>0\,$ :

$$\left|\, e^{iz|x|}-e^{i\lambda| x|}\,\right|=|\,e^{i|x|a-b|x|}-e^{i\lambda |x|}\,|\le e^{-b|x|}+1\le 2$$

Note I dropped the square...and thus you're right!

Comment: I think you use $x$ to denote two different quantities at the same time.

Comment: Yup, I already edited that. Thanks.

Comment: OK, luckily we got the same result ...